# Computer software of the cancelled Yahoo!Instant Messenger/chats services

Tags: windows-live-messenger

yahoo cancelled its Instant Messenger recent years, leaving my precious IM chats unsaved. When asked for help, Yahoo IM reps gave me links of those chats in HTML format. I appreciate very much if anyone can help me convert those HTML links into readable text form.

Comment: Have you tried to view them in a browser? Or paste into a word processor configured with a new web document?

Comment: You may wish to have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328356/3395469). In short, you would want to download and install [the Python scripting language](https://www.python.org), then use one of the solutions suggested (such as [html2text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text) or [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)). Obviously, you would need to download the chat logs in HTML format first (as a suggestion, you might want to check out [the Python request module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for that).